# Jquery clone with class

Tags: jquery

I could clone the table, but the class datepicker doesn't work in clone lines.

I don't know if I can use find to get it.

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Location</td>
    <td>From</td>
    <td>To</td>
    <td>Add</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tr_clone">
    <td><input type="text" autofocus placeholder="who" name="who" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" autofocus placeholder="location" name="location" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Start Date" name="datepicker_start" class="datepicker"></td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="End Date" name="datepicker_end" class="datepicker"></td>
    <td><input type="button" name="add" value="New" class="tr_clone_add"></td>
</tr>
```

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
});


$("input.tr_clone_add").live('click', function() {
var $tr    = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
var $clone = $tr.clone();
$clone.find(':text').val('');
$clone.find('datepicker_start').addClass("datepicker");    
$tr.after($clone); 
});
```

Comment: btw, live() is depreciated.

Comment: .`find(':text')` that's a new approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safest(and faster) to clone needed element, before you apply datepicker on it, (you can also remove class `hasDatepicker`) :

```
var $to_clone = $('.tr_clone').first().clone();
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
});


$("table").on('click', 'input.tr_clone_add', function () {
    var $tr    = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
    var $clone = $to_clone.clone();
    $clone.find(':text').val('');
    $tr.after($clone);
    $clone.find('.datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/yWpBm/

Answer (score 1):

When you clone the widgets properties will not get copied also I don't think there is a selector called `:text`, Try

```
$("input.tr_clone_add").live('click', function() {
    var $tr    = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
    var $clone = $tr.clone(true, true);
    $clone.find('input').val('');
    $clone.find('.datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
    });    
    $tr.after($clone); 
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CKpbb/)

Comment: ok, this line worked 
    $clone.find('input').val('');
but 
`$clone.find('.datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
    });` doesn't work.

The calendar opens always the first line.